# Segfault while sorting vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

As an exercise I implemented the quicksort algorithm in a template, and it "works fine" for vectors with low number of elements (up to about 760), but gives a seqfault for higher number of elements. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
template< typename Vector, typename VecElem > void qsort(Vector *pv)
{
    if (pv->size()<=1) return;

    VecElem p;
    Vector *pvl=new Vector,*pvr=new Vector;

    p = pv->back();
    pv->pop_back();
    pvr->push_back(p);
    for (auto it=pv->begin();it!=pv->end();it++)
    {
        if (*it < p) pvl->push_back(*it);
        else pvr->push_back(*it);
    }
    qsort<Vector,VecElem>(pvl);
    qsort<Vector,VecElem>(pvr);
    if (pvl->size()) *pv = *pvl;
    if (pvr->size()) std::copy(pvr->begin(), pvr->end(), std::back_inserter(*pv));
    delete pvl;
    delete pvr;
}
```

Comment: Why do you allocate the temp vectors on the heap?

Comment: Your recursion goes too deep and exhausts all the available stack space.

Comment: Use iterators or indices rather than creating a new vector.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck:(and DCoder) it was because of the segfaulting that I removed the references and replaced with pointers (I've got plenty heap-space), but that did not solve it. If I have 765 elements, it segfaults.

Comment: Measure how many times this function gets called to sort that long vector (print a line to the console or something similar).

Comment: The vector allocates space for storage on the heap anyways so you're saving minimal space by creating the vector itself on the heap.

Comment: Is the vector already sorted? `p = pv->back();` will cause problems if it is.

Comment: @ahenderson: no, it's filled with random numbers, but how will it cause problems?

Comment: Does it work correctly for small numbers? After quicksort recursion calls, you assign left vector to result and then copy left vector again!!

Comment: @saeedn: thx for spotting that - fixed it. I used iterators to copy the values previously, and during browsing SO I came across the `back_inserter` technique, which I then used for both copying pvl & pvr - this is a case of copy/paste without fixing - but it still segfaults. I'm now trying DCoder's suggestion of printing info on each recursion ..

Comment: @DCoder: your comment appears to be correct, even for 10 items it recurses to a depth of 19!~ why? how can I fix it?

Comment: Because that's how many times you are asking it to qsort various subsets of the original vector. Do what ahenderson originally suggested, work with iterators/indices instead of creating new vectors and use `std::swap` to swap elements.

Comment: @DCoder: the issue isn't which existing STL code to use, it is an exercise for me to learn C++, I do try to implement existing things (because the result is easy to verify by just using the existing things), so that later when I do something new, I would not panic too much and know how to go about debugging it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other have pointed out, your implementation is not efficient when e.g. sorting ascending data. However, this is not the reason for your segfault. The problem in your code is that you do not exclude the pivot element during the partitioning phase.

Simply try to sort a vector that only consists of two identical elements (e.g., {0,0}). It will loop infinitely.

To fix the problem, insert the pivot element after you have sorted both vectors.

Maybe this works (at least it fixes the stack overflow):

```
pvr->push_back(p); // remove this line

// and insert it later...
qsort<Vector,VecElem>(pvl);
qsort<Vector,VecElem>(pvr);
pvl->push_back(p); // this line is new
```

Comment: That is spot-on correct :) Thank you. (So simple - would have taken me a month of Sundays to suspect)